# Google Maps alternate route current traffic

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I would like to show a map and list of different routes, considering current traffic.
This can be done with the Google Maps app, as one of the navigation options.

In my app I would like to offer the start and end point (and preferably optional intermediate waypoints as well) directly. I tried to make this with the Google Maps API Direction Service, which allows for all except for the current traffic option. The business options seems not really attractive for just-for-fun project.

Is there an option to directly fire the Google Maps app to this thee possible route view? Anyone knows how to form an intent to get this done?